# How to make a view in Storyboard's scene dock be adaptive?

Tags: storyboard, xcode7

Xcode 7 allows a view to be added to a [scene dock](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/Chapters/AddViewsToDock.html).  However, the documentation does not specify how that scene can be made adaptive so it changes its form factor depending on the size class of your device.  The view is not relative to any superview so there is no way for it to be constrained to a superview.

How do you make a view in Storyboard's scene dock be adaptive?

Answer (score 1):

Create an outlet in the code and add constraints programmatically. For example:

```
    let margins = self.view.layoutMarginsGuide
    yourView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    yourView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    yourView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

    yourView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0).isActive = true


    yourView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 260.0).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add to the other David's answer.

> The view is not relative to any superview so there is no way for it to be constrained to a superview.

Yes there is!

```
view.addSubview(yourSceneDockView)
// or
view.insertSubview(yourSceneDockView, at: 1)
```

Only after this can constraints be applied to make the view adaptable.